# How to set a Python alias in a Singularity container upon execution?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, docker, alias, singularity-container

I have been trying to set some aliases in my container but I haven't been able to do it successfully. While building the container I put `alias python3=python3.6` in `%post` and things work fine; the alias is correctly declared and is used throughout the container building process.

However, after the container is built and I execute it, using `singularity exec`, the alias declaration in `%environment` or`%runscript` does not work. I also tried putting the alias declaration command in a bash script in the container and run the bash script but it still does not work. Basically, I think I'm looking like **ENTRYPOINT** in Docker for Singularity. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can set aliases within a container?

I'm using Singularity 2.6.

Here's the definition file I'm using:

```
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:16.04

%post
# Set up some required environment defaults
apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install software-properties-common && yes '' | add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install make \
                                        cmake \
                                        vim \
                                        curl \
                                        python3.6 \
                                        python3.6-dev \

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6

alias python3=python3.6 #Here's where I declare the alias

python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install -U setuptools
python3 -m pip install  scipy \
                        numpy \
                        transforms3d \
                        matplotlib \
                        Pillow

# I also create a file containing a bash script to declare the alias
cd /
mkdir bash_aliases && cd bash_aliases
echo "alias python3=python3.6">bash_aliases.sh
chmod +x bash_aliases.sh


%runscript
alias python3=python3.6

# bash /bash_aliases/bash_aliases.sh # You may uncomment this as well
```

Comment: there is an entrypoint script in docker world , there might be something like that in singularity

Comment: @IjazKhan Yes I think I'm looking for something similar

Comment: no , i didnt , but i deleted my answer just because it was not complete

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not possible to set an alias for the `exec` mode when using a container it is however possible to do it for `run` mode using the script below:

```
%runscript
    alias python3='python3.6'
    eval ${@}
```

The difference between `exec` and `run` is that `exec` runs the command you write directly but `run` passes whatever you write to the script you've written in `%runscript`.

[Source](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/2273)

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to set aliases for the `shell` mode?